# Sorting data in keystone.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, keystonejs

I am new to `keystone.js`. I have a data in this format:

```
{ _id: 5551823e7771fc3f0decb03e,
       slug: 'marketing-manager',
       title: 'marketing manager',
       __v: 0,
       description: '<p>marketing stuff</p>',
       location: 'London',
       order: '2',
       orderno: 2 
},
{
       _id: 5552fb667ebab90c0e8b0440,
       slug: 'a-web-developer',
       title: 'a Web developer',
       __v: 0,
       description: '<p>Keystone web developer.</p>',
       location: 'India',
       order: '1',
       orderno: 1 
}
```

I want to order these data with `orderno`.

And I am using this query:

```
view.query('Jobs', keystone.list('Job').model.find().sort('orderno'));
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: Given query is not working properly. I mean it doesn't sort the list by orderno.

Comment: You say "it doesn't sort the list". What is the result of the query?

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestions from **[this](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-querying)** and **[that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/keystonejs/fZ9tqrlpkFI/acZa44K3ZaoJ)**, you could try the following:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Job = keystone.list('Job');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res); 
    // LOAD Jobs
    // ------------------------------   
    view.on('init', function(next) {        
        Job.model.find()            
            .sort('orderno')
            .exec(function(err, jobs) {
                if (err) return res.err(err);
                res.jobs = topics;
                next();
            });

    }); 

    view.render('site/jobs');   
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this works EDIT works.. my updated keystone uses sortOrder

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for sortinng.

```
model.find().sort({name: 'criteria'}).exec(function(err, model) { ... }
```

And `criteria` can be any of the below:

```
asc, desc, ascending, descending, 1, or -1
```

Here, asc, ascending and 1 is `Ascending` Order And desc, descending and -1 is `Descending` Order.